# how to make the program access any type of file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a universal email extractor. I have gone through a program which is as below:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import os.path
import re

regex = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
                    "{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
                    "\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))

def file_to_str(filename):
    """Returns the contents of filename as a string."""
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().lower() # Case is lowered to prevent regex mismatches.

def get_emails(s):
    """Returns an iterator of matched emails found in string s."""
    # Removing lines that start with '//' because the regular expression
    # mistakenly matches patterns like 'http://foo@bar.com' as '//foo@bar.com'.
    return (email[0] for email in re.findall(regex, s) if not email[0].startswith('//'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser(usage="Usage: python %prog [FILE]...")
    # No options added yet. Add them here if you ever need them.
    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args:
        parser.print_usage()
        exit(1)

    for arg in args:
        if os.path.isfile(arg):
            for email in get_emails(file_to_str(arg)):
                print (email)
        else:
            print ('"{}" is not a file.'.format(arg))
            parser.print_usage()
```

I ran this program and it worked fine with `.txt` and `.csv` extension file.

but the problem is the folder through which I am giving input to this program also have `.xsls`,`.doc`,`.docx`,`.mdb`, `.pdf` and other extension files, also having emails in them. I do not understand how I can modify my program to access these or any type of extension file and extract emails out of them.

Kindly, let me know suggestions how I can resolve my issue.

Comment: Many files (such as `xlsx` and `docx`) are compressed. Others (like `doc` and `mdb`) are in proprietary formats. You cannot just run a regular expression on the raw contents and expect to be able to find an email address.

Comment: The formats you mention are binary, they are not designed to be read as text and cannot be treated as such.  You could naively scan them for recognisable strings under the assumption they appear as plain text in-situ, but this wont work reliably, .docx for example is compressed.  The corrrect way to do this is to use a parser appropriate to the file type in question.

Comment: So is there no way around without using parser to read the files. Even as binary if I read the files then will it be possible to extract the emails from the files?

Comment: Consider that you *do* in fact have an algorithm that can extract email addresses from any file it comes across. By definition such an algorithm can break any/all encryption.

Comment: @JafferWilson just open one of the .docx/.pdf files in Notepad an see what text you would have to work with, its not possible without a parser or other code that understands the underlying file format.  Windows does this with search indexing using custom IFilter providers, you could see if there is an API you could use, although I can't imagine there is one for a mdb. (I use Agent Ransack for searching, it uses IFilters & understands regex criteria)

Comment: is there no way to create a unviversal file reader with python so that performing operations will become easier?

Comment: Sure, just learn the file formats for each file type and write a parser for each.  big job tho, thats why there is no universal VIEWTHISFILE.EXE

Answer (score 0):

you should open file with 'rb' flag

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
```

note that doc, pdf, ... are not text file so for each type you need special parser to parse the content

Comment: Using `rb` will I be able to extract the emails from any file?

Comment: no, but in python3 when opening binary files without 'b' flag you will get `UnicodeDecodeError`

Comment: Do you think that you answer can be answer to my question? please can you elaborate how it is helpful to me in my situation. As I said I am trying to create an email extractor from any type of file.